# What's the 254 symbol in ascii, is it ■ or þ?

Tags: unicode, ascii

Looking at this page https://www.asciitable.com I see that the 254 symbol is a filled square (■). But here: https://www.ascii-code.com it says it's the small letter thorn (þ).

When using the symbol in code as 0xFE on a Mac using the Swift language I get the thorn letter (þ), then how do I get the square (■) in ascii?

Using this tool https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html and (■) as input I get a number larger than 255, so it can't be represented in ascii then?

Comment: ASCII goes up to 127.

Comment: Don't trust everything you see online. As @Macmade says ASCII only goes up to 127, anything beyond is some other character set. You need to figure out which one.

Comment: If you want to know role of the code _254_ (= `0xFE`) then check [Encodings of Unicode Character 'BLACK SQUARE' (U+25A0)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/codepage_support.htm) by code page, or try in Python: `print( chr(254), chr(254).encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'cp437'))` returns `þ ■` and vice versa `print( chr(0x25A0), chr(0x25A0).encode( 'cp437').decode( 'cp1252'))` returns `■ þ`.

Comment: The third link (rapidtables) doesn't even give correct answers.  Don't use it.  For example, 80 returns the Euro symbol for ISO-8859-1, and it doesn't exist in that encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.

ASCII determines characters for codes 0-127. There is no default "Extended ASCII". Meaning of all other codes depends on actual encoding. In your second link the used encoding is CP-1252 as it clearly states there. In your third link you get [Unicode code for BLACK SQUARE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm) as a fallback, there is no ASCII code for the black square anyway.